# Synchronisation issue with error on Meteor

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

Hey I have an issue to manage my error on my Meteor apps, I search about this kind of things and I found some topics about synchronous functions but I can's manage my problem. On my client side I call a method and I need to have the result before to go through. 
My client side :

```
onSubmit: function(doc){ // Gestion du formulaire d'inscription
        var error = null;
        var title = doc.title;
        var content = doc.content;

        var formData = {
            title: title,
            content: content
        };
        //get the captcha data
        var captchaData = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        Meteor.call('createCPDM', formData, captchaData, function(err){
            if(err){
                error = new Error("Une erreur s'est produite");
            }
        });

        if(error === null){
            this.done(); // Appelle onSuccess
        }
        else{
            this.done(error); // Appelle onError
        }

        // reset the captcha
        grecaptcha.reset();
        return false;
    },
```

My server side :

```
createCPDM: function(formData, captchaData) {
    var ip = "0.0.0.0";
    var verifyCaptchaResponse;

    if (!this.connection.clientAddress) {
        verifyCaptchaResponse = reCAPTCHA.verifyCaptcha(ip, captchaData);
    }
    else {
        verifyCaptchaResponse = reCAPTCHA.verifyCaptcha(this.connection.clientAddress, captchaData);
    }

    if (!verifyCaptchaResponse.success) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('422', 'reCAPTCHA Failed: ' + verifyCaptchaResponse.error);
    } 
    else {
        var CPDMID = CPDM.insert(formData);
    }

    return true;
}
```

So I need to know if I have an error before continue...

Thank's for your help !!!

Comment: Javascript is mostly a **Asynchronous** language so put everything after `Meteor.call` inside the callback

Comment: @Endless Actually I can't do that because I need to have access to `this.done()`

Comment: Simply change `function(err){}` to `err => {}` and then you get access to `this.done`

Comment: or do something like `var self = this` & `self.done()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES6**

```
onSubmit: function(doc){ // Gestion du formulaire d'inscription
    // preventDefault() ????
    var formData = {
        title: doc.title,
        content: doc.content
    };

    //get the captcha data
    var captchaData = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    Meteor.call('createCPDM', formData, captchaData, err => {
        if(err) {
             // Appelle onError
            return this.done(new Error("Une erreur s'est produite"));
        }

        this.done(); // Appelle onSuccess
        grecaptcha.reset();
    });
}
```

**ES5**

```
onSubmit: function(doc){ // Gestion du formulaire d'inscription
    // preventDefault() ????
    var formData = {
        title: doc.title,
        content: doc.content
    };

    //get the captcha data
    var captchaData = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    var self = this

    Meteor.call('createCPDM', formData, captchaData, function(err) {
        if(err) {
             // Appelle onError
            return self.done(new Error("Une erreur s'est produite"));
        }

        self.done(); // Appelle onSuccess
        grecaptcha.reset();
    });
}
```

Comment: The first solution ES6 doesn't work for me but the second one do the job ! Thank's

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.call` never returns the server-side return value synchronously.

If you want to use the result of a server-side computation in Meteor, the only way to do that is in the callback function. Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call):

> If you include a callback function as the last argument [...]
>   the method will run asynchronously: it will return nothing in
>   particular and will not throw an exception. When the method is
>   complete [...] the callback will be called with two arguments: error
>   and result.

You could maybe display a user-facing notification (like a spinning wheel) until the callback gets the server-side result.

Comment: Thank's for your answer ! I understand the idea and I had the same but I don't know how to "block" the client side to wait the server-side result...

Comment: You don't block in JavaScipt. If you need the "this" variable, use the arrow function syntax that keeps the "this" value. Like so: `Meteor.call("some", () => { this.boo(); });`